# density of numbers that have relatively the same output of euler phi as input

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\phi_a(n)= 1$ if $\phi(n) \geq \frac{n}{a}$ and $0 $ otherwise. where $\phi(n)$ is Euler phi function.

Let $S_a(x) = \sum \limits_{n \leq x} \phi_a(n)$ and $M_a = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{S_a(x)}{x} $ if the limit exists.

Trivially we have $M_a \leq 1$ for  all $a \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$.

The lower bound trivially is $M_a \geq 0$, with a little work we have $ \sum \limits_{n \leq x} \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \approx \frac{6}{\pi^2}x$ so we can say that $\sum \limits_{n \leq x , \phi_a(n)=1} \frac{\phi(n)}{n}  + \sum \limits_{n \leq x , \phi_a(n)=0} \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \leq \sum \limits_{n \leq x , \phi_a(n)=1} 1  + \sum \limits_{n \leq x , \phi_a(n)=0} \frac{1}{a}  = S_a(x) +\frac{x-S_a(x)}{a} $

So we have that $S_a(x)+\frac{x-S_a(x)}{a} \geq \frac{6}{\pi^2}x $ and so $M_a (1-\frac{1}{a}) \geq \frac{6}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{a} $ so for $a\geq 2$ we have that $M_a \geq \frac{\frac{6}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{a}}{1-\frac{1}{a}}$

For instance $a=2$ gives that $M_2 \geq  0.11773 $

Its better than the trivial bound but still not quite good, is there a more cleaver way to find $M_a$ ?

For all $a> 1$ since for $0< a\leq 1$ we have that $M_a=0$

Comment: Otherwise good question, and I don't think there's an easy way to find $M_a$.

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks, will fix

Comment: can your question instead to be find better bounds? I doubt someone will find the exact answer

Comment: @mathworker21 if no exact answer is found, i am very happy with better lower,upper bounds.

Comment: well, if $a$ is something like $1000$, then for $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \prod_{p \mid n} (1-\frac{1}{p})$ to be less than $\frac{1}{a}$, you'd need $n$ to have many, many prime factors, at the very least at least $k$ prime factors, where $k$ is the smallest number with $\prod_{j=1}^k (1-\frac{1}{p_k}) \le \frac{1}{a}$, where $p_1,p_2, \dots = 2,3,5,\dots$ are the primes in increasing order.

Comment: This paper may help. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-039-02/S0002-9947-1936-1501849-X/S0002-9947-1936-1501849-X.pdf

Comment: $M_a$ can be treated as the Cdf of a particular random variable, whose natural logarithm has a real expected value implying that $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}=1$